# Нужно сделать так, чтобы у человека играющего в игру начинался таймер в 10 секунд во время того как он будет вводить слово

Tags: python, разработка-игр

```
import time

print('(Небольшая инструкция по мини игре)')
print('В мини игре вам будет дан ряд из 11 символов типа: (a8РrоC5тоtК) и вам нужно будет составить слово из 5 букв в данном случае Росток')
a18 = input('На ответ вам будет дано 10 секунд вы готовы начать? варианты ответа: Да: ')
if a18 == 'Да':                                            
    while True:
        print('еCГ7uр2амlм')
        a19 = input('Введите слово')
        time.sleep(10)
                                                                                            
        if a19 == 'Грамм':
            print('Победа')
        else:
            print('Вы проиграли')
            break
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы у человека играющего в игру **начинался таймер в 10 секунд** во время того как он будет вводить слово.
То есть, чтобы таймер шел даже до того, как человек введет что-то в input, а если не успеет　ввести за 10 секунд или введет не то слово то выведется надпись *Вы проиграли* но если успеет ввести слово *Грамм* за 10 секунд то вывод *Победа*.
Знаю что модуль time для этого не подходит так что нужна ему **замена** .

Появилась проблема с тем что скрипт должен "Умирать" когда кончается таймер
вот код:

```
import time
from threading import Timer

print('В мини игре вам будет дан ряд из 11 символов типа: (a8РrоC5тоtК) и вам нужно будет составить слово из 5 букв в данном случае Росток')
a18 = input('На ответ вам будет дано 10 секунд вы готовы начать? варианты ответа: Да: ')
if a18 == 'Да':                                            
    while True:
        print('Уровень 1')
        print('еCГ7uр2амlм')                                                                                          
        ti = 10
        t = Timer(ti, print, ['Время вышло'],)
        t.start()
        p = "У вас есть %d секунд чтобы ввести слово\n" % ti
        a19 = input(p)

        if a19 == 'Грамм':
            print('Победа')
            time.sleep(0.2)
            print('Уровень 2')
            print('sЛk2е5сg1ка')                                                                                     
            ti1 = 8
            t1 = Timer(ti1, print, ['Время вышло'],)
            t1.start()
            p1 = "У вас есть %d секунд чтобы ввести слово\n" % ti1
            a20 = input(p1)
            if t1 == 0:
                break
            if a20 == 'Леска':
                print('Победа')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528939/time-limited-input

Comment: @splash58 Появилась другая проблема скрипт должен ломаться по окончанию времени но этого не происходит. Сейчас добавлю правку